# Newletter Module with captcha in prestashop

Tags: captcha, prestashop, newsletter

I am looking for a good newsletter module in prestashop with captcha in it and easy to handle in backend too. please recommend a good module

Answer (score -1):

This module shows a slide (like in iphone) that you need to scroll to unlock the form and send.
Usefull to avoid unwanted bots in your forms.
You can add to any form in your site.

**Features:**

- Multilingual
- Cross browser
- Easy to use

[Link](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/114958-module-slide-captcha-20-add-a-captcha-to-your-forms-support-iphoneipad/page__hl__captcha)